# Get image from drawable by path

Tags: android

I am trying to get image that inside drawable folder by path
so i try this but not working

```
  String path = "android.resource:///" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "/drawable/logo_ataturk";
    File imgFile = new File(path);
    if (imgFile.exists()) {
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

        ImageView imgLogo = findViewById(R.id.imageView_logo);
        imgLogo.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources are not files on the device. They are files on your developer machine, nothing more.

You can replace all of this code with:

```
ImageView imgLogo = findViewById(R.id.imageView_logo);
imgLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_ataturk);
```

Comment: i wil store the logo path in database ,
when i getting data it will show the logo image by path value.

cause all of that i am trying to get image by path

Comment: @Modgo: You can store the resource name (`logo_ataturk`) in the database, then use `getResources().getIdentifier()` to derive the resource identifier (the `R.drawable` value) at runtime. Again: there is no path to resources on the device.

Answer (score 2):

I found this simplest solution

```
  Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +  "/drawable/logo_ataturk");
    ImageView imgLogo = findViewById(R.id.imageView_logo);
    imgLogo.setImageURI(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(getResources()
                  .getIdentifier($name_of_the_image, "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

or

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.large_icon);
imgLogo.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Comment: You're wellcome!